# How to copy a directory in C++, using std::filesystem::copy?

Tags: c++, copy, filesystems, std

So, I'm trying to do something that should be simple. I'm using `std::filesystem::copy` to copy one directory into another, as such:

```
#include <filesystem>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const char* dir1 = "C:\\Users\\me\\folder";
    const char* dir2 = "C:\\Users\\me\\folder_copy";
    std::filesystem::copy(dir1, dir2, std::filesystem::copy_options::update_existing);

    return 0;
}
```

However, the above crashes for me when `folder_copy` already exists, with the following error:

`Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF932E9A308 in code.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::filesystem::filesystem_error at memory location 0x00000012188FF6D0.`

Interestingly, the flag `std::filesystem::copy_options::overwrite_existing` works fine for me. Is `update_existing` incompatible with `std::filesystem::copy`? It would be weird if it only worked with `std::filesystem::copy_file`.

Anyway, if this is by design, how do I copy a directory while only updating out-of-date files?

Comment: `rsync`! I'm not sure C++ has a built-in method for this.

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes"?

Comment: @DrewDormann `Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF932E9A308 in code.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::filesystem::filesystem_error at memory location 0x00000012188FF6D0.
`

Comment: @Danny Catch the exception and print out the message.

Comment: @TedLyngmo duh, I should always start there. The error is: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". Which means that I must have one of these files open somewhere, and I guess that's only a problem when using the `update_existing` flag? I'll update this question with an answer if that's the problem.

Comment: It could  just as well be the _reading_ of the file that causes the problem since you're on Windows. You could use a recursive directory iterator and try copying them one by one to find out which one it doesn't want to copy if the execption doesn't show that.

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    namespace fs = std::filesystem;
    const char* dir1 = "C:/Users/me/folder";
    const char* dir2 = "C:/Users/me/folder_copy";

    try {
        fs::copy(dir1, dir2,          
            fs::copy_options::update_existing
            //|fs::copy_options::overwrite_existing
            |fs::copy_options::recursive);
    }
    catch (const fs::filesystem_error& e) {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also check that no file in the destination folder is in use while being updated and that you have sufficient write permissions.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't fix it for me.

Comment: @Danny And now?

Comment: did you try copying some other dir with a single text file only ? just to make sure that no hard/soft links are causing some trouble. did you also make sure that the file being updated is not already opened and in use ?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Nope, that didn't do it. I copied my paths over wrong, they are double-slash delimited.

Comment: @StPiere you might be onto something, this works when I replace the contents of the folder with a single text file. However, I can't modify the original folder contents in production, since I don't "own" them. Is there anything that can be done without modifying the folder contents?

Comment: With "don't own" you probably mean you have no sufficient write permissions ? Can you modify the folder content by copying by hand ? If no and you're running the .exe with your account, then the prog won't have permission either. It looks like a permission issue (at least for some files).

Comment: you can also try catching those exception and printing out to get some meaningful error message. see update.